# How to click the button "Change confidential mode" in gmail? Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to click the confidential button that appears in gmail with selenium, but I have not been able to click it.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('a3I').click()
```

[image]

And try click on button "Guardar" (save):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('Guardar').click()
```

[image]

How can solve this? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
//*[@id=":s2"]
```

If you press F12 on your keyboard and do a CTRL+F and search by xpath (//), that will be your result. I searched it by the id of the element. Please let me know of it works for you.

The solution is:

```
composeEmail9 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.buc.aaA.aMZ')
composeEmail9.click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Guardar']").click()
```

Comment: Nop, I get this: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Comment: composeEmail9 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.buc.aaA.aMZ')
composeEmail9.click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Guardar']").click()